# Selenium won't send keys to Instagram comment box

Tags: python, selenium

When trying to make a Selenium bot that comments on Instagram pictures, the bot will click on the comment box, but the keys will not send. Interestingly though, when I manually click the comment box myself, the keys will send. I'm unsure what's going on here as the box appears to be clicked just fine, but keys will not send without me manually clicking on it. I'm new to both Python and Selenium... And programming in general.

I've tried adding a delay between the click() and the send keys but to no avail. I still have the same issue. I've also tried sending the keys more than once, with again, a delay between them. But again, this does not work. I'm certain that I have the class name correct, as the bot appears to find the box, the problem is with the send key. I've searched and searched and I know others have had this same issue but no solution has worked for me, that's where I got the idea of sending the keys twice, as well as adding a time delay. This is the code in question below -

```
comment = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Ypffh").click() 
time.sleep(5)
comment.send_keys("test")
time.sleep(5)
comment.send_keys("test")
```

And here is what I'm seeing when inspecting the Instagram comment box -

```
<textarea aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" class="Ypffh" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;"></textarea>
```

EDIT -----

I have updated the code to this but still not having any luck.

```
comment = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "Ypffh")))
            comment.click()
            comment.send_keys("test")
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `send_keys` to a `click` that returns a NONE.

Just change it to:

```
comment = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Ypffh")
comment.click() 
time.sleep(5)
comment.send_keys("test")
time.sleep(5)
comment.send_keys("test")
```

It is best practice to use `WebDriverWait` not `time.sleep`

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

comment = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "Ypffh")))
comment.click()
comment.send_keys("test")
comment.send_keys("test")
```

Comment: I have updated my code to this but it's still doing the same thing - the box appears to be clicked but the keys aren't sending. Very strange and frustrating

Comment: @before570 what did you do? please edit it into the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebDriverWait to try and make sure the browser can click on the textarea before sending the keys to it. Also, its not completely necessary but I like to save the elements that I know I will use a lot at the top using By.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

TextArea = (By.CLASS_NAME, "Ypffh")
#Initialize browser and go to proper page same as before...

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(TextArea)).send_keys("Whatever you want to Type")
```

Another possible problem could be the time.sleep() calls. It doesn't take into account your operating systems process scheduler which can cause the sleep to be more or less than what you actually pass to it. A better option is selenium's implicit_wait().

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Then i tried first click on the comment box element and then send keys .
It just worked out for me

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[3]/div/form/textarea').click()
time.sleep(1.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[3]/div/form/textarea").send_keys("nice post,Keys.ENTER)#comment
```